# I have values blank but I don't need to show word of null

Tags: java, android

I have 4 values of Strings imported from different activities I want to display in one TextView.

But when you display the values on the phone, the imported values are blank and they are appearing on the screen as null and Ido not want the word null to show. How can I canceled it?

This code you used to display the values and set this condition but did not succeed. Is the code wrong ???

```
public class Order extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText nam;
private EditText address;
private EditText phon;
String sandwish;
String snack;
String juice;
String pizza;
int sandwishI;
int snackI;
int juiceI;
int pizzaI;
TextView orderSummaryTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_order );
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle b = i.getBundleExtra( "personBdl" );
    sandwish = b.getString( "string" );
    snack = b.getString( "name" );
    juice = b.getString( "value1" );
    pizza = b.getString( "value2" );
    sandwishI = b.getInt( "INT" );
    snackI = b.getInt( "INT1" );
    juiceI = b.getInt( "INT2" );
    pizzaI = b.getInt( "INT3" );
    final String textMessages = allText( sandwish,snack,juice,pizza );
    displayMessageSandwish( textMessages );

private String allText(String sandwish,String snack,String juice,String pizza) {
    String string = "";

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty( sandwish )) {
        orderSummaryTextView.setError( "empty" );
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty( snack )) {
        orderSummaryTextView.setError( "empty" );
    }

    return string;
}

private void displayMessageSandwish(String mSandwish) {
    orderSummaryTextView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.order_sandwish );
    orderSummaryTextView.setText( mSandwish );
}
```

I have added a picture from my phone about the appearance of the word Null where the imported value is empty

[image]

Comment: Just check `if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(value))` for each value.

Comment: Can you post how you send those extras please from Activity1?

Comment: You need to show us a [mcve] of where `personBdl` comes from, please. Also, `return string` appears to always be empty

Comment: please show the code where you pass the data from other activities

Comment: It is a long code because there are orders to send from several activities to the main activity and then send all the imported data from main activity to another activity presented by all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method to solve this.

```
private static String removeIfNull(String clearMe){
   return clearMe == null ? "" : clearMe;
}
```

And use it as;

```
snack = removeIfNull(b.getString( "name" ));
juice = removeIfNull(b.getString( "value1" ));
pizza = removeIfNull(b.getString( "value2" ));
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `allText(String, String, String, String)` is always an empty String. Therefore `displayMessageSandwish(String)` is always called with an empty `String` parameter.

Although you're not presenting a complete example I would assume, that the resulting screen appears because you set the text of the `TextView` in the underlying layout file - or on a completely different place in your code.